# virtualboxを起動している間、USBでルーターに接続できない

Tags: windows, virtualbox

ホストOS:Windows7 -> Windows10
バージョン:virtualbox 5.0.0.101573、5.1.14.112924

普段WimaxルータをUSB接続してネットに繋いでいます。
virtualboxを起動すると、インターネット接続なしになります。
virtualboxを終了してUSBを挿し直すとまたWimaxルーターが認識されてネットに繋がるようになります。
virtualboxを終了せず挿し直しても繋がりません。
USB自体の不具合かと思いUSBメモリを指した状態でVirtualboxを起動したところ、USBメモリは正常に認識され続けています。

「コントロール パネル\ネットワークとインターネット\ネットワーク接続」を見ていると、普段は「イーサネット3」として認識されているWimaxルータがVirtualboxを起動した瞬間消えてなくなります。
Virtualbox側のネットワーク設定をすべてクリアし、仮想NICもなくした上でWimax以外のネットワークデバイスを全て無効にしても挙動に変化は見られませんでした。
Virtualboxを終了せずにUSBを挿し直すと、一瞬だけ「イーサネット3」が表示されてすぐに消滅します。

何度かVirtualboxを再インストールし直しましたが治りません。

Comment: @sken2 ありがとうございます。
`コントロール パネル\ネットワークとインターネット\ネットワーク接続`　からwimaxのルータ以外のネットワークアダプタを無効にしてみましたが改善しませんでした。
最悪クレードルを買ってみます。

Comment: 仮想マシンを起動している間、ですよね。その仮想マシンの設定で、ネットワークアダプターやUSBコントローラーを無効化してみるとどうでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist
コメントありがとうございます。
＞コメント欄
了解です。
＞仮想マシンを起動している間
いえ、virtualboxを起動しただけで（たとえ仮想マシンが一切登録されていなくても）ホストOSのネットワーク接続が切れます。

Comment: 仮想マシンの`設定→USB`がどうなっているか教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBoxが内部のソフトウェアブリッジを構成する際に、USBにつながったルータより先にLANアダプタを見つけてしまうのでそのような現象が発生するのでしょう。
たぶん使ってない内蔵LANアダプタがあると思うのですが、それをコントロールパネルで無効にすれば改善するかもしれません。（つまり、存在をVirtualBoxに伝えないようにするわけです）
それでもだめなら、WiMaxのルータをクレードルなどを使ってLAN経由にするしかないと思います。